# Select Between two dates in sql

Tags: sql

We are facing problem when we'r trying to select records from a table between two dates.

Table structure/datatypes:

```
    Slno (int, notnull, IsIdentity(yes))  
    Name (string(50))
    StartDate (datetime)
    EndDate (datetime)
```

Sample Data:

```
Slno    Name      StartDate                   EndDate
 1      ABC       2017-02-17 00:00:00.000     2017-02-25 00:00:00.000
 2      ABD       2017-02-15 00:00:00.000     2017-02-25 00:00:00.000
 3      ABD       2017-02-17 00:00:00.000     2017-02-17 00:00:00.000
 4      ABD       2017-02-14 00:00:00.000     2017-02-18 00:00:00.000
 5      ABD       2017-02-17 00:00:00.000     2017-02-20 00:00:00.000
```

We tried running the below sql query:

```
select * from dbo.XYZ where (getdate() between StartDate and EndDate)
```

The output is:

```
Slno    Name      StartDate                   EndDate
 1      ABC       2017-02-17                  2017-02-25
 2      ABD       2017-02-17                  2017-02-20
```

We are not getting other three rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What datatypes are startDate and EndDate?

Comment: `Slno` = 2 has `StartDate` = 2017-02-15  and `Enddate` = 2017-02-25. Is that a typo in your output? Also, please add output of `getdate()`, people may view this question in the future.

Comment: The datatypes of startDate and EndDate is datetime.

Comment: Slno StartDate and Endate both are different.

Comment: getdate() means currentdate and time

Comment: make a test with  `where convert(date, getdate())  between StartDate and EndDate`

Comment: We tried the conversion also we are getting the same result.

Comment: Your query returns the expected output for me..

Comment: But if the data types are date time, why have you not included the time portion in your example data?

Comment: What database are you really using? GETATE() is a Sql Server function, but `string` and `IsIdentity` are **NOT** Sql Server names.

Comment: MSSQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE EndDate >= GETDATE()
  AND StartDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE());
```

This will use your defined indexes as much as possible.

See [bad habits to kick mishandling date range queries (Aaron Bertrand)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) for more on this.

Comment: That makes no sense. Please provide an accurate testing case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, but as Todd commented why time is not included in output if data type is datetime?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.XYZ 
WHERE StartDate <= GETDATE() 
    AND EndDate >= GETDATE()
```

EDIT:
Looks like you are storing date, not datetime, so try below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.XYZ 
WHERE StartDate <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
    AND EndDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

EDIT:
Not really sure how else I can help, are you on SQL Server, Oracle etc? Below script will show you how date and datetime data types look like (SQL Server), and this is what confusing me the most as you are claiming your data type is datetime but output looks like date.

```
SELECT 
cast(GETDATE() as datetime),
cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

Comment: can you run below and let me know the output, I need to check what data are you storing: select top 1
 getdate() as CurrentDateTime,
 StartDate,
 EndDate
from dbo.XYZ

Comment: the output you can on top i.e. second table

Comment: Run query from my comment

Comment: After running your query we are geeting same result. i.e. second table

Comment: Looks like you need to provide more info: what is actually data type in columns, is query you have given full query or only part of the query?

Comment: Datatypes of Slno (int, Auto Increment), Name(String,)StartDate(datetime),EndDate(datetime)

Comment: If they are datetime, they should have a timestamp. Show it.

Comment: @user3128590, I am NOT going to downvote your question but this is pure sample how simple question with very little details can become hard to answer. You need to spend more time to specify question, provide data samples, tag correct DBMS etc, then you will save time as you will get answer much quicker.

Comment: PawelCz I have clearly specified question and the result and also Sample.

Comment: As Todd said, if date type would be datetime then output should have datestamp so 2017-02-17 15:21:26.493 not 2017-02-17

Answer (score -1):

Getdate() means currentdate and time. So the above query return 2 rows.

You can refer this query:

```
declare @minDate datetime
declare @maxDate datetime

select @minDate = MIN(StartDate) from dbo.XYZ
select @maxDate = MAX(EndDate) from dbo.XYZ

    select * from dbo.XYZ where @minDate<= GetDate() OR @maxDate >= GetDate().
```

It will return all rows.

Comment: Won't this return all rows in the database, no matter what the dates are?

Comment: "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Comment: We are getting error <b>'An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.'</b>